# How to add an AWS::ApiGateway::Resource to an AWS::Serverless::Api in CloudFormation template

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-cloudformation, aws-api-gateway, aws-serverless

In my CloudFormation template I create a Serverless::Api resource like so,

```
Resources:
  RestApi:
    Type: AWS::Serverless::Api
    Properties:
      StageName: v1
      Auth:
        DefaultAuthorizer: DefaultAuthorizer
        Authorizers:
          TokenAuthorizer:
            FunctionArn: !GetAtt AuthorizerFunction.Arn
```

Then I want to add a custom resource to this API, to do that I add this resource to my template

```
Resources:
  ShareResource:
    Type: AWS::ApiGateway::Resource
    Properties:
      ParentId: !GetAtt RestApi.RootResourceId
      RestApiId: !Ref RestApi
      PathPart: 'share'
```

When I deploy the `CloudFormation` template, it works and I get no errors, however, the custom `ShareResource` is not in the API, it doesn't exist anywhere. However, when I look at the `CloudFormation` event outputs, it says the resource was created.

How do I achieve this?

Comment: did you click the resource to see where its taking you ?

Answer (score 0):

Just a hunch, but this potentially could be caused from not putting any methods inside the resource. try adding a child AWS::ApiGateway::Method to your resource and see if cloudformation builds correctly. E.g.

```
Resources:
  RestApi:
    Type: AWS::Serverless::Api
    Properties:
      StageName: v1
      Auth:
        DefaultAuthorizer: DefaultAuthorizer
        Authorizers:
          TokenAuthorizer:
            FunctionArn: !GetAtt AuthorizerFunction.Arn

  ShareResource:
    Type: AWS::ApiGateway::Resource
    Properties:
      ParentId: !GetAtt RestApi.RootResourceId
      RestApiId: !Ref RestApi
      PathPart: 'share'

  MockMethod:
    Type: 'AWS::ApiGateway::Method'
    Properties:
      RestApiId: !Ref RestApi
      ResourceId: !Ref ShareResource
      HttpMethod: GET
      AuthorizationType: NONE
      Integration:
        Type: MOCK
```